# Views contextual filter from user registration field

Tags: 7, views

On user registration i have added field PROFILE (field_profile) which is used as company name. Each company can make simple galleries.

Tokens are used to create all content for all users.
For main content profile i have:

www.example.com/companyname (field_profile) (where comapnyname is used from PROFILE field).

For gallery links are made like this:

www.example.com/companyname/gallery/node1
www.example.com/companyname/gallery/node2
www.example.com/companyname/gallery/node3

I need help with creating view:
www.example.com/%/gallery - which would list all node galleries made by the user.

This link would only be available in sidebar block when someone lands on:
www.example.com/companyname  or
www.example.com/companyname/gallery/node1,2,3

Gallery node is content type which has hidden field field_userprofile which is autocreated and uses token [node:author:field_profile] which is also used to create the "gallery" part of the link and auto node title which both work fine.

Comment: You left out a critical part, how are these gallery pages created?

Comment: I have updeated the question.

Comment: Do you have problems with the contextual filter, or the display of the block?

Comment: I did not try the block yet, although i have idea how to get block working after i get contextual working first.

Comment: `www.example.com/%/gallery - which would list all node galleries made by the user.` is the user name the company name?

Comment: Profile (field_profile) which is part of registration fields is used for %.